# display all data in select form in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using cakephp. and want to display all data in database in dropdown list. but it returns only last item. there is some problem in loop. my code is below.

```
foreach ($origions as $or);
$id = $or["origions"]["id"];
$orgn = $or["origions"]["origion"];
$options = array($id=>$orgn);
echo $this->Form->select('origions.origion', $options);
```

this display only last record in dropdown list. please help what to do that all data in table display over here.

Comment: You're declaring a new array at each loop, hense it only returns a single array value. Declare `$options = array();` beforehand then either append or push to array.

Comment: *In fact* the foreach isn't doing anything, as it's appended by a semicolon

Answer (score 2):

Change it to,

```
$options = array();
foreach ($origions as $or){
   $id = $or["origions"]["id"];
   $orgn = $or["origions"]["origion"];
   $options[$id] = $orgn;
}
echo $this->Form->select('origions.origion', $options);
```

For **selected**,

```
echo $this->Form->select('origions.origion', $options, array('value' => 'your_default_id'));
```

*[Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aselect)*.

Comment: thanks its working fine. one more thing what to do for selected value.

Comment: You can give `id` you wants to get selected by default in third parameter. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. one last thing more how to display an label with it for e.g Origin : this is last question thanks

Comment: Pass `label=>"your_label"` in third parameter after value.

Comment: echo $this->Form->select('origions.origion', $options, array('value' => $origin,'label'=>'Origin')); i place this code but label doesn't print.

Comment: Than rather use `label` form helper.`echo $this->Form->label('Origin');` just above your select option.

Answer (score 0):

**OTHER WAY (more optimized code)...**

You can set Your data `$this->set`  from the controller.
From controller You can **combine** / extract / merge / sort / etc... **multidimensional arrays** like:

```
$result = Set::combine($origions, '{n}.origions.id', '{n}.origions.origion');
```

Read more about **Cakephp SET::array functions** http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html